# Why run this error when I use __getitem__ in python OS, list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Tags: python, pytorch

```
class My_custom(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  def __init__(self,path:str,transform=None):
    self.path=os.listdir(root)
    self.root=path #Main path, where train and test folder are in
    self.dir=os.listdir(root+self.path[0])
    self.transform=transform
    self.img_name=[]
    self.file_name=[]
    for i in range(len(list(self.path))):
      for a in range(len(self.dir)):
        self.img_name.append(os.listdir(f"{self.root}{list(self.path)[i]}/{self.dir[a]}"))
  def __len__(self):
    count_file=0
    for i in range(len(self.img_name)):
      count_file=count_file+int(len(self.img_name[i]))
    return count_file
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    # print("Sweet")
    # load_imag
    file_path=[]
    for i in range(len(self.path)):
      for a in range(len(self.dir)):
        idx=(os.listdir(f"{self.root}{self.path[i]}/{self.dir[a]}"))
        for file_name in range(len(idx)):
          file_path.append(f"{self.root}{self.path[i]}/{self.dir[a]}/{idx[file_name]}")
    print(file_path[2])
    return file_path[idx]
   [idx]}"))
Data=My_custom(path=root)
Data[2]
```

I try different ways to using for to get file path without using Pathlib library, I expect get a custom dataloader from Pytorch

Comment: Please include the full error message and your directory structure so we can help you better

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: <ipython-input-21-53ece2ab8d49> in <cell line: 28>()
     26     return file_path[idx]
     27 Data=My_custom(path=root)
---> 28 Data[13]

<ipython-input-21-53ece2ab8d49> in __getitem__(self, idx)
     24         for file_name in range(len(idx)):
     25           file_path.append(f"{self.root}{self.path[i]}/{self.dir[a]}/{idx[file_name]}")
---> 26     return file_path[idx]
     27 Data=My_custom(path=root)
     28 Data[13]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Comment: the code return all data set, but i expect come on at time,

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the `idx` variable in `__getitem__` with a list, then return with `return file_path[idx]`.